# Creating a Pandas data frame using already existing saved variables?

Tags: python, pandas

This is probably something basic but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Let's say I have variables created during the process, for example mean absolute error (MAE) calculations (floats). I then have mae_a, mae_b, mae_c, and mae_d. If I'd like to save those to a data frame in pandas, what would I do? 
It'd be nice if it was something intuitive like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mae_a, mae_b, mae_c, mae_d)
```

But obviously it isn't that - or I needn't ask.

EDIT: I have understood that I can do like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['mae_a', 'mae_b', 'mae_c', 'mae_d'],
                   'MAE':[mae_a, mae_b, mae_c, mae_d]})
```

To get:
 [image]

I leave this question unanswered to see if someone has an answer where I don't have to write "mae_a" &c two times - as that would be the ideal.

Comment: what is in the variables?

Comment: Mean absolute error calculations - so floats.

Comment: `pd.Series({'mea_a': mae_a, ...})` or `pd.DataFrame({'mea_a': mae_a, ...})`?

Comment: You have to write `"mae_a"` multiple times because you made a choice to create a variable number of variables, instead of deciding to properly store them in some single container. You should store your variables in a dict `d = {'mae_a': whatever_function_returns_the_value, ...}`

Comment: @ALollz Thanks. This is news to me. when I've done a prediction and I wan't to see the mae score I usually put somethin like: `mae_lr = MAE(y_te, y_pred)`could I instead write something that stores it in a dict(ionary?) and that for every time I calculate another mae it adds to another "row" in the dictionary? And if so - please write an answer about it.

Comment: Yes, if these are from multiple predictions then you could loop over the predictions, and perhaps add a label in the loop. For instance something like `d = {}; for label, y_col in [("mae_a", y_pred1), ("mae_b", ypred_2)]: d[label] = MAE(y_te ,y_col)`...

Answer (score 1):

If you store your values in a dictionary then you won't have to rewrite the columns when building the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
values = {'mae_a': [4.55, 4.66],
          'mae_b': [3.66, 4.66],
          'mae_c': [5.77, 4.66],
          'mae_d': [6.88, 7.55]}


df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df = pd.melt(df, value_vars=df.columns)
print(df)
```

which gives this output

```
  variable  value
0    mae_a   4.55
1    mae_a   4.66
2    mae_b   3.66
3    mae_b   4.66
4    mae_c   5.77
5    mae_c   4.66
6    mae_d   6.88
7    mae_d   7.55
```

Comment: This comes close. I was just imagine it to be long df instead of a wide. But I think I can figure out how to do that now that you've given me this :) Let me try.

Comment: I did figure it out but unfortunately it's not as easy as I would've liked since you can not turn the variable names into one column and the variables into another column to make a df of two columns automatically - it's just the variables them selves - I have to name the variables twice - once as string and once to get the floats. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Mactilda updated to return data in shape you want hope this helps

Comment: Thanks - I edited the question to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
a = 1,2,3,4,5
b='a','b','c','d','e'
d = pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':b})
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   c
3   4   d
4   5   e
```